# Relation between differentiation and linear transformation

Tags: derivatives, linear-transformations

> **Definition.** A map $F:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ is said to be differentiable at a point $p\in\mathbb R^n$ if there exists a linear tranformation $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ such that
> $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\lVert F(p+h)-F(p)-T(h)\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0,\tag1$$
> where on the left the norm in the numerator is in $\mathbb R^m$ and that in the denominator is in $\mathbb R^n.$

It can be shown that $T$ is unique and we denote it by writting $T=DF(p)$ and call it the derivative of $F$ at $p.$ Furthermore, $DF(p)\in L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m),$ the space of all linear transformations from $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^m.$

---

I'm struggling to understand the above definition. I have been trying to relate this notion of differentiability in $\mathbb R^n$ with the one in one dimension. I mean we all know that if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a differentiable function on $\mathbb R$ and $a\in\mathbb R,$ then:
$$f^\prime(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h\tag2.$$
Furthermore, $f^\prime(a) (=m,\text{ say})$ gives the slope of $f$ at the point $a,$ and so we can define a linear function $x\mapsto mx,x\in\mathbb R,$ with the help of differentiation of $f$ at the point $a$ which nearly behaves the same as the function $f$ itself around the point $a$ (if I am not wrong!) in $\mathbb R$. That is, $f^\prime(a)$ (considered as a function) is actually linear in nature and also from $(2),$ we can write:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-hf^\prime(a)}h=0.$$
The above equation/condition is (kind of!) similar to $(1).$ So, is this how differentiation and linear transformation are related to each other in $\mathbb R^n$ as well? Or, there's more to it. I'm confused! Please give some insights...

(Sorry... if such a question had already been answered before.)

Comment: $f'(a)$ itself is not a function, and certainly not linear. The linear function that acts as the differential here is $h\mapsto hf'(a)$.

Comment: @CheeringRhino Understood sir. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is differentiable at $a$ then, as you wrote$$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h,$$which is equivalent to$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)h}h=0.\tag1$$Now, consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}T\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&f'(a)x.\end{array}$$This is a linear map and it follows from $(1)$ that$$\lim_{h\to0}\left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-T(h)}h\right|=0,$$which is the same thing as asserting that$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\bigl|f(a+h)-f(a)-T(h)\bigr|}{|h|}=0.$$

Comment: Ahh.. yes sir. I missed the factor $h$ while transposing $f^\prime(a)$ on to the right in equation $(2)$ and typed only $\ldots-f^\prime(a)$ in the numerator. (Shall I correct it in my post?) I have understood your answer perfectly. Thank you sir.

Comment: Since I have corrected what you wrote, there's no need for you to do the same thing, but I have no objections. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks.. I've added the factor $h$ in the numerator. (It was poking my eyes!)